# In Google Query, return 0 to cell when query returns empty set for a particular month

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

Using Google Query, I would like to return 0 to a cell when the query returns an empty set for a particular month in 2018.

This is the query I am using with the named range `all_data`:

```
=query(all_data,"SELECT SUM(A) WHERE F <> 'Converted' GROUP BY MONTH(N),1)
```

Column N contains a list of dates.  The output I am getting is:

```
blank_cell
1
2
4
14
```

But what I would like to get based on the dataset, if blank months returned as 0, is

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
2
4
14
```

Note there are 12 values in my desired output, each corresponding to a particular month.

Once I figure out the above, my next challenge will be figuring out how to do this for 2 years worth of data (2017-2018).

So far I have

- Checked [the Google Query documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) but couldn't figure it out there
- Tried using `IFERROR` - doesn't help because there is not technically an error occurring

My strong preference is to implement this using `QUERY` rather than `VLOOKUP`, `SUMIF`, or some other function because that is how the rest of the data in this analysis is being generated and consistency will help other users of the sheet.

Thanks for any ideas you have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way may be to make sure your data set has at least one instance of every month without `Converted` in ColumnF and with `0`s in ColumnA.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution - thanks!  Rather than add to my data set, I created a separate named range on a separate sheet called `fix_month` which excluded the header, and used an array as my data for the Query function, to get `=query({all_data; fix_month},"SELECT SUM(Col1) WHERE Col6 <> 'Converted' GROUP BY MONTH(Col14),1)` . Note for some reason the introduction of an array didn't like naming columns by letter, which is why I changed to the ColX notation.  Works great.